# How to import modules in eagle schematic files into kicad correctly and how to create similar eagle module in kicad?

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, kicad, symbol, module

I have just started learning kicad and schematic design. I am trying to import MKR 1500 arduino eagle files to kicad. I am able to load all the schematic symbols except shifter1. My import procedure: In kicad File->Import Project->EAGLE CAD and select the either .brd or .sch file.

How can I import eagle file so that shifter module is also loaded correctly? How can I create a similar module(shifter) in kicad?

Image of the shifter1 when opening the schematic in eagle cad:
[image: Schematic in Eagle]

On clicking the child node in Shifter(1) it takes to another sheet. Image of the Module->Sheet:
[image]

When I open the schematic in kicad, shifter module is missing. See image below:
[image]

My Kicad version: 5.1.10

OS: ubuntu18.04.1

[MKR 1500 eagles files link](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/MKRNB1500-reference.zip)

Comment: I tried this v5.99 and faced the same issue. I guess its not supported? is it possible to save the module as a seperate eagle schematic and them impor that again to KiCAD?

Comment: @HemalChevli I am not sure. I however created a hierarchical sheet with hierarchical labels. I am not sure if it is the correct way to go about.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround and was able to get the shifter module schematic into KiCAD.
[image]

Here is how I did it.
In Eagle create a new sheet(you cannot do this in the free version), copy the shifter module contents to this new sheet. Save the project and then import it into KiCAD, all three sheets will be imported.

You will have to use this hierarchical sheet in place of the 'Shifter' module and use hierarchical labels to make the connection.

Comment: To do this in the free versios of Eagle, simply open the the `.sch` file in a text editor, search for `</sheet>`, then add `<sheet/>` immediately after it and save the file. When you open the schematic in Eagle, there will be a new blank sheet in the schematic.